Nested component and child route loading issue inside shell app using module federation
Scenario : Shell app Angular version 16 and MFE angular version 13 (multirepo workspace), now i am trying to expose Example Module inside shell app, Example component having wrapper component containing  i want to load module withe left-nav and section where children route should mount inside shell app.
Note:- Inside MFE itself everything is working fine, issue is with shell app. also attaching screenshots.
I tried with router outlet name but even the issue is there. I want to consume Example module inside shell app.webpack.config.js
Example ModuleExample Routing Module
Wrapper component of example module which contains router outlet to mount its child
Output of MFE
Output of Shell app

Please do not share screenshots of code, provide the code directly in your answer in a way where we can use it to reproduce your error, even bettter you could share a StackBlitz.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
